# Mixing languages in the same SSML

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, ssml

If I send this small piece of SSML to the speech processor I get two voices

```
<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='es-ES'>
  <voice xml:lang='es-ES' xml:gender='Male' name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (es-ES, Pablo, Apollo)'>
    <p>
        <s>Hola </s>
        <s xml:lang='en'>Hello</s>
        <s>¿Cómo estas?.</s>
    </p>
  </voice>
</speak>
```

A man in Spanish and a woman in English. Is this a limitation of the Project Oxford Text to Speech engine? in other words, I would expect the same voice to speak several languages but it looks like this is not the case.

Comment: Amazon polly does have the same voice try to pronounce the second language and it's in my opinion a worse outcome as the voice sounds like the second language was learned as a second language and is hard to understand.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The question was asked in 2016 and I think today it is obsolete. Processors today are much better than in 2016

Comment: No. I am faced with the same issue today. I just got azure cognitive tts(formerly oxford) working in my app today finally with two different languages but different voices. Amazon polly requires a single language specified and different languages just sound bad when pronounced with a non-native voice. Alexa skill seems to support it but I"m not sure. Google cloud does not support two languages. I'm trying to save someone the same time I spent researching the options for bilingual apps, not answer your question.

Comment: Amazon Polly has truly bilingual voices, but they are just a few. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/bilingual-voices.html In general, TTS voices are not created multilingual (much harder to train).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the SSML [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.1.2),

> Specifying xml:lang does not imply a change in voice, though this may indeed occur. When a given voice is unable to speak content in the indicated language, a new voice may be selected by the processor.

While the current fallback behavior leaves something to desire, the recommendation is to create multiple voice nodes and pick a voice more explicitly when switching languages.